# Groovy-XML Attribute adding with condition

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

I have a xml file and csv file i have tried updating my xml with the csv values but it is not getting added and returns null value.

The xml file csv content are shown below respectively..

```
def xmldata='''<data>
<TYPE name="Semester1">
<SUBTYPE name="girl" age="21"/>
</TYPE>
<TYPE name="semester2">
<SUBTYPE name="boy" age="23"/>
</TYPE>
</data>'''

def csv='''name,name,mark
semester1,girl,50
semester2,boy,75'''
```

I want to check if `TYPE.name` and the `SUBTYPE.name` of csv matches with xml and update them.

```
def root2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmldata)
root2.TYPE.SUBTYPE.find{it.@name=='girl')}.@mark=50 //this is adding the values
```

How to check `TYPE.name` matches with `SUBTYPE.name` and add mark as another attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that going to add in semester1.

```
root2.TYPE.find{it.@name=='Semester1').SUBTYPE.find{it.@name=='girl')}.@mark=50
```